# Person/Group picker infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I am having a problem with Person/Group picker field in infopath form. It was working fine until last week and since then this field is not working. When I type a name its not recognising the names or when I click on Add People from address book its not opening the directory too.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Delete the people picker field and then recreated it in infopath and publish the form, compare the results.